# what does this command line do?

Tags: bash, command-line

I am working through this resource: https://cmdchallenge.com

On the following challenge: https://cmdchallenge.com/s/#/search_for_files_containing_string, the problem was:

```
Print all files in the current directory,
one per line (not the path, just the filename)
that contain the string "500".
```

When I ran:

```
ls -al
```

I got the following:

```
    total 36
drwxr-xr-x.  2 501 dialout 4096 Feb 10 21:08 .
drwxr-xr-x. 39 501 dialout 4096 Apr 18 19:04 ..
-rw-r--r--.  1 501 dialout  204 Apr 29 17:44 README
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 501 dialout   23 Feb 10 20:59 access.log -> ../../common/access.log
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 501 dialout   25 Feb 10 21:08 access.log.1 -> ../../common/access.log.1
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 501 dialout   25 Feb 10 21:08 access.log.2 -> ../../common/access.log.2
```

I tried a few things, then looked at the user submitted solutions and one of them was:

```
ls *[^2]
```

I did some googling and the man page (and here), but I can't see what this is doing, or how it works.

Can anyone point me to a decent resource so I can read up on it, or tell me how it works?

Comment: See e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62660/the-result-of-ls-ls-and-ls

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers

Comment: The reference you are looking for is in the manual under: [pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching). `*` matches any string, `[^2]` matches any character that is **not** `2`. So the command lists all files that do not end in `2`.

Comment: I don't see how that would satisfy the requirements "all the files in current directory that contain the string "500" in the filename".

Comment: It seems the "user submitted solutions" may not actually solve the challenge.

Comment: @JNevill if you look at the challenge. Then the directory contains 4 files. From those 4 files, only 3 contain the string "500". The solution `ls *[^2]` is actually cheating as it assumes you already know the solution which files they are, so you just exclude the one file that it is not.

Comment: By the way, here's the resource describing glob patterns: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching

Comment: @kvantour Thank you. That makes more sense. I was reading the question as "print out filename, one per line, where the FILENAME contains "500"" and I couldn't figure out why anyone would bother with those 4 files. This all makes sense now. And that is a crap answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let me first quote PesaThes comment to what the command does:

> The reference you are looking for is in the manual under: [pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching). `*` matches any string, `[^2]` matches any character that is **not** `2`. So the command lists all files that do not end in `2`

Now why this is a solution to the problem is not so clear from your question alone. But if you look what the files contain you will notice that indeed, `access.log.2` is the only one that does not contain the string `500` and also the only one whose name ends in `2`.

For other sets of files the command `ls *[^2]` will most probably not output all the files without the string `500` in it, but in this case with those specific files it matches the right files. Another solution would have been for example

```
echo README; echo access.log; echo access.log.1
```

Comment: I didn't realise that the 'l' command looked inside the files! I nearly didn't post this question, but I am glad I did now as I learned something cool!

Comment: @leonsegal I do not understand what you mean. No command mentioned in either your question or my answer looks "inside the files". I know what the content of the files is because I went to the challenge website and did `cat access.log.1`.

Comment: you're right - I was getting mixed up

Answer (score 1):

that's not an answer to your question, the right way of doing it is

```
$ grep -sl 500 * .*
```

`-s` skip errors (caused by directories); `l` only filenames; search in `*` all visible files and `.*` invisible files.